# XNA - Interaction between objects that move with the camera and those who don't

Tags: c#, camera, xna

I'm working on a 2D game, and right now I'm facing a problem that I can't proceed without solving it. In my project, I first draw the things that don't move with the camera, and than the things that always stay in the same place (mostly UI elements). My in-game mouse's rectangle is set for the Mouse position + the camera centre in both X and Y.

So, while the player can click on UI elements (I use the Intersects function between the mouse and the button for now, I'm leaving most of the work on the UI to the end), if I try to do any interaction between the mouse and anything that actually moves with the camera, it doesnt work since the mouse's coordinates "compared" to the camera, while the object is not, and I have no idea how to make it work.

Here is the code of the camera:

```
class Camera
{
    public Matrix transform;
    Viewport view;
    Vector2 centre;
    int x;
    int y;

    float zoom;

    public Camera(Viewport newView)
    {
        view = newView;
        x = 0;
        y = 0;
        zoom = 1;
    }

    public Vector2 getCentre()
    {
        return this.centre;
    }

    public void Update(GameTime gametime)
    {
        if (Mouse.GetState().Y < 45 && y >= 5)
            y -= 3;
        if (Mouse.GetState().Y > 400 && y < 650)
            y += 3;
        if (Mouse.GetState().X > 580 && x < 90)
            x += 3;
        if (Mouse.GetState().X < 60 && x > -100)
            x -= 3;
        centre = new Vector2(x, y);

        transform = Matrix.CreateScale(new Vector3(1,1,0)) * Matrix.CreateTranslation(new Vector3(-centre.X,-centre.Y,0));
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Viewport.Unproject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.graphics.viewport.unproject.aspx) method transforms vector in screen space to vector in world space.

Supply it with vector with X and Y mouse coordinates and your projection view world matrices. The result would be a vector in your world space. You can use it's cordinates to compare with objects bounds.

If you need an intersection between mouse pointer not as a point, but as a rectangle, with bounding rectangle of some object, opposite method [Viewport.Project](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.graphics.viewport.project.aspx) might help.
What you need is to project top-left and bottom-right corner vectors of bounding rectangle of moving object, build rectangle using result vectors, and call intersect between result rectangle and mouse rectangle.